# Change pandas column values to become lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Currently, I have

`df['fruits']`

```
apple,
orange,
pineapple,
banana,tomato,
cabbage,watermelon,

Name: fruits, Length: 5, dtype: object
```

How can I change the above to lists and remove the commas at the end in pandas dataframe?

Expected output of `df['fruits']`

```
[apple]
[orange]
[pineapple]
[banana,tomato]
[cabbage,watermelon]

Name: fruits, Length: 5, dtype: object
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, but perhaps `df['fruits'].str.split()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. combine `rstrip` and `split` by `,`:

   ```
   df['fruits'].str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')
   ```
2. or just split by `,` and skip the last (empty) chunk:

   ```
   df['fruits'].str.split(',').str[:-1]
   ```

---

```
0                  [apple]
1                 [orange]
2              [pineapple]
3         [banana, tomato]
4    [cabbage, watermelon]
Name: fruits, dtype: object
```